# Example of $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $E[g(Z)\mid M=\mu]=0, \forall \mu \in C$ where $Z$ is Gaussian and $C$ is an ellipse.

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, gaussian-integral

Let $Z \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be an i.i.d. Gaussian vector with mean $M$ where $P_{Z|M}$ is it's distribution.

**Question:** I am looking for an non-trivla example of function $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{align}
E[g(Z)\mid M=\mu]=0,  \forall \mu \in C
\end{align}
where $C=\{\mu: \frac{\mu_1^2}{r_1^2}+\frac{\mu_2^2}{r_2^2}=1 \}$. That is, $C$ is an ellipse.

**Some Thoughts**: I was able to find an example of $g$ when $r_1=r_2=r$ that is when $C$ is a circle.  For example, let
\begin{align}
g(x)= \|x\|^2 -(2-r^2)
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
E[g(Z)|M=\mu]&= E[\|Z\|^2 \mid M=\mu]-(2-r^2)\\
&=\operatorname{Var}[Z \mid M=\mu]+ \|\mu\|^2-(2-r^2)\\
&=2 +r -(2-r)=0
\end{align}

However, I was not able to find an example of such a function if $C$ is an ellipse but not a circle.

Comment: You say "Where $P_{Z\,\mid\,M}$ is$\,\ldots$", but then you never use that notation is the rest of what you write. Why introduce a notation that you never use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

If $\ f(x)=\frac{x_1^2}{r_1^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{r_2^2}\ $, what is $\ E\big[f(x)\,\big|\,M=\mu\big]\ $ for $\ \mu\in C\ $?

Comment: Ok. I got it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if this is a unique solution up to scalar multiplication?

Comment: No, I don't.  After playing around with the question for a few minutes, I couldn't see any obvious simple way of answering it.

Comment: Should I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: Ok. I asked this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4163003/is-gx-fracx-12r-12-fracx-22r-22-c-a-unique-solution-of-eg